# Как хранить котировки валют

Tags: php, mysql, json

Написал скрипт который парсит котировки валют со многих бирж, потом данные все нужно анализировать и выдавать некие результаты. Данный скрипт потом напишу но нужно как-то хранить огромные массивы данных, данные только числовые с плавающей точкой. Чтоб понять какой объём данных, наведу пример:

1. Пар примерно 15 000. Каждую пару нужно хранить как минимум неделю,
   минутные данные, так как буду анализировать недельные данные.
2. В идеале для статистики и исторических данных нужно хранить все время все данные.
3. Если хранить недельные данные то получиться: 10 080 * 15 000 = 151 200 000.
4. Если год то 525 948 * 15 000 = 7 889 220 000 строк.

---

Возник вопрос, где хранить данные недельные и как хранить данные за все время исторические. Выдержит ли недельные данные mysql, а исторические данные хранить в файлах json, и потом по надобности считывать, так как исторические данные буду юзать редко. А вот недельные данные будут довольно часто анализироваться скриптом, примерно раз в минуту.

---

Структура таблицы примерно такая:

> 1. id
> 2. id_market
> 3. last_price
> 4. market_volume
> 5. base_volume
> 6. datetime_edit
> 7. datetime_add

Comment: смотря что вы хотите с ними делать и на сколько сильно манипулировать.

Comment: Исторические данные будут редко использоваться. А вот недельные - будет скрипт которые будет анализировать недельные данные для разных сигналов. Тоесть он будет раз в минуту вытаскивать данные из базы - не перезаписывая. Недельные данные только записываються новые а самые старые удаляться.

Comment: Если ТОЛЬКО `INSERT` то `mysql` осилит. Если индексированные запросы на выборку - осилит. Если что-то сверху, то придется смотреть в сторону более практичных БД, хотябы в сторону постгреса.

Comment: Я бы отталкивался от того, что потом с этими данными должно происходить. какой именно анализ выполнятся. будет ли этот анализ происходить на стороне БД, потому что если нет и БД будет использоваться только как хранилище, а для анализа надо будет подгружать весь набор целиком в скрипт, то возможно их бы стоило вообще хранить в файлах, двоичных. А если все таки анализ в БД, то надо смотреть позволяет ли выбранная СУБД быстро выполнять требуемые вам преобразования

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте обратить внимание на [ClickHouse](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/ru/) от Яндекса. Это столбцовая СУБД, заточенная под как раз аналитику. Очень шустрая и прекрасно документированная. Синтаксис там, насколько мне известно, SQL + собственные комнады.

Comment: У кликхауса болезней тоже хватает, то что быстрая спору нет, но рентабельности не оправдывает. Все-же лучше правильные индексы.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL совершенно не боится 8 млн. строк весь вопрос состоит в индексах и составных индексах. К примеру дату добавления можно разбить на колонки year как SMALLINT, month как TINYINT, day как TINYINT и сложить их в составные индексы (2,1)+(1) байт. Так-же неделю можно уложить в INT который с каждой неделей прибавляет +1 вот вам и сокращение данных для поиска... Устаревшие данные у которых неделя > например месяца можно просто нулить через (null) и NULL в индексации вовсе не учитывать - таким образом мы получаем относительно короткий индекс недель и.т.д.

Такая методика была проверена на биллинговой системе где происходит около 2к записей/обновлений в секунду.

Очень старые данные (Архив) можно откачивать отдельной задачей по крону раз в месяц и хранить их например в Mongo. Но следует заметить что Mongo хоть и является очень быстрой БД - но совершенно бесчеловечно относиться к дисковому пространству и жиреет прямо на глазах.

Comment: А в чем смысл разбивать дату на колонки, да она конечно места меньше займет, но там у ТС данные то минутные, так что придется еще время хранить и выборка данных за последнюю неделю, если например сегодня 2 января превратиться в что то жуткое. И откуда вы взяли цифру 8 млн строк, у ТС в расчетах приведено 150 млн в неделю ...